# How to automatically scale up and down Amazon EC2 ubuntu micro instances

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am building a project in which i use amazon EC2 micro instance as a server which is running ubuntu on it. I want that if the resources of this server e.g. RAM to serve the requests are exhausted , it should automatically scale up and down . I have heard of it very often but don't know how to make this instance automatically scalable.
I connect to my instance using ssh through command line and i can make it start and stop etc. using AWS Management Console in browser.

Comment: What you want is called vertical scaling. While it may be doable in a roundabout way, it requires an instance restart. EC2 autoscaling works best with horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, when you are talking about auto scaling you are dealing with a system that adds more instance in response to more demand, and deleting instance in response to dwindling demand.

I am not saying its impossible to autoscale a single instance, but if you can, its at a minimum going to require the instance to go off-line for a bit while it reconfigures itself and reboots. Usually not an option for a lot of systems.

Much better, imo, to architect your solution to use **additional** instances when you need more horsepower if possible and delete those instances as they become idle instead of sizing up or down a single instance.

Comment: Mr. E.J. can you please refer me some good tutorial to do this thing

Comment: This is probably your best starting place: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/